# passing array to javascript

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm working on a project with a classmate, neither of us have previous experience with php and javascript. Our goal is to query a db and store the results in an array then pass that array to a javascript function. My partner wrote this bit of code which works but I was unable to successfully pass the array to our function in our javascript.

First, I tried using a local array which worked out fine when I tested it. Then I tried with the array generated in the above php segment, I've seen this question asked a few times but when I tried implementing some of the suggestions to encode the array as a JSON object that didn't work. Is there something wrong with the way we store the results from the database? I appreciate any help.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM predictions ORDER BY course_no DESC";
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result and $result->num_rows != 0) {
        @$result->data_seek(0);
        while($classesArray = @$result->fetch_assoc()) {
            extract($classesArray);
            echo $course_no . "<br>";
        }

      @$result->free(); // Release memory for resultset 
      @$db->close(); 
      echo " <script>var a = json_encode($classesArray);</script>";
}
?>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        //var a = ["class1", "class2", "class3"];
        //loadClasses(a);'

        loadClasses(a);
    });      

function loadClasses(classesArray) {
    // #classesfield is the id of the classes dropdown
    for (var i = 0; i < classesArray.length; i++) {
        $("#classesdropdown").append('<input class="w3-check" type="checkbox">'); // add checkbox to our dropdown
        $label = $('<label class="w3-validate"></label>'); // crete element to inject
        $label[0].innerHTML= (classesArray[i]); // give it a class label
        $("#classesdropdown").append($label); // add it to our dropdown
        $("#classesdropdown").append('<br>'); // add new line to the dropdown
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Remove all of the `@` chars in your code, they prevent error reporting and you will not be able to know if you have some errors in your code or not. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You should have your PHP page get called using AJAX.

Comment: try to echo the entire <script> element

Comment: @Dekel I'm just not populating a dropdown with the data from the array when I try using the array generated in the php.

Comment: what is `loadClasses` function? what is the actual output (the final html) you have?

Comment: Your PHP page should grab the query and echo the encoded JSON back out. The JavaScript should make an AJAX call to retrieve the results as JSON and that data should populate the page.

Comment: posting the rest of the loadClasses() in one sec..

Comment: What are the table fields (other than `course_no`) for your `predictions` table?

Comment: @TravisHallet do I still need to encode in my javascript after that? Or can I just pass that array like so: `loadClasses(a);`

Comment: I would just use that to get my variable then do the code in a script field

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl `ind INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 dept VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
 course_no VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 term TINYINT NOT NULL,
 year INT NOT NULL,
 projection INT NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is to have a simple HTML page which requests the JSON via an AJAX call to a PHP page which in-turn fetches the Database data, processes it, and returns JSON data.

### SQL Data

I made up the following data as an example, but the PHP does not care about the fields. You will just return all the data in the table as a JSON object array.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
  `course_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `course_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_credits` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `course` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`course_no`);

INSERT INTO `course` (`course_no`, `course_name`, `course_desc`, `course_credits`) VALUES
(1, 'Algebra', 'Learn how to perform basic arithmetic.', 4),
(2, 'Biology', 'Learn how to classify organisms.', 4),
(3, 'Literature', 'Read a lot of books.', 4),
(4, 'Physical Education', 'Get active!', 2);
```

### retrieveClasses.php

Connect, query, and return the class information from the database as a JSON array.

```php
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', '', 'test');
$myArray = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `course`")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

### index.html

Populate the dropdown with the JSON data returned from the AJAX call.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ajax Populate Using PHP DB</title>
        <meta name="description" content="PHP Database Ajax Populate">
        <meta name="author" content="Self">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $.getJSON('./retrieveClasses.php', function(records) {
                    loadClasses(records.map(function(record) {
                        return record['course_no'] + '] ' + record['course_name'];
                    }));
                });
            });

        function loadClasses(classesArray) {
            // #classesfield is the id of the classes dropdown
            for (var i = 0; i < classesArray.length; i++) {
                $('#classesdropdown').append('<input class="w3-check" type="checkbox">'); // add checkbox to our dropdown
                $label = $('<label class="w3-validate"></label>'); // crete element to inject
                $label.text(classesArray[i]); // give it a class label
                $('#classesdropdown').append($label); // add it to our dropdown
                $('#classesdropdown').append('<br>'); // add new line to the dropdown
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="classesdropdown"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```